# Why isn't my <li> rendering properly on the page?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a simple, short, unordered list to appear on my page, but for some unknown reason it shows as plain text, not in list form. Here is my code:

```
<section id="rightContent">
    <h2>HAVEN'T REGISTERED YET?</h2>
    <p id="para">Lorem ipsum  consequat, sit amet tempor eros ornare. Ut tincidunt, mauris vel pretium egestas, lacus velit vestibulum ante, non fermentum erat neque eleifend augue.</p>
    <br>
    <section>
    <ul>
      <li>Donec eu tellus tortor. Cras varius leo ac dolor congue, ac volutpat risus placerat.</li>
      <li>Suspendisse tellus nisi, feugiat tincidunt sollicitudin sit amet, interdum tempor nunc.</li>
    </ul>
    </section>
    <br>
    <a href="#">SIGN UP NOW</a>
</section>
```

Comment: The code is there it just need edit approval.

Comment: Seems to work fine - here https://jsfiddle.net/8k60t7mh/

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Lists</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>List of my favorite things</h1>
  <ol>
   <li>Raindrops on roses</li>
   <li>Whiskers on kittens</li>
   <li>Bright copper kettles</li>
   <li>Warm woolen mittens</li>
  </ol>
  <h2>'List of things I find just OK'.</h2>
  <ol>ordered list
  <li>jjj</li>
   <li>mee</li>
    <li>jjkk</li>
    </ol>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: @sonukumar Don't post code in the comments.

Comment: Could you select the code in your question and press ctrl + K so we can read it?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when I use the same HTML. Here is the snippet of it

```html
<section id="rightContent">
    <h2>HAVEN'T REGISTERED YET?</h2>
    <p id="para">Lorem ipsum  consequat, sit amet tempor eros ornare. Ut tincidunt, mauris vel pretium egestas, lacus velit vestibulum ante, non fermentum erat neque eleifend augue.</p>
    <br>
    <section>
    <ul>
      <li>Donec eu tellus tortor. Cras varius leo ac dolor congue, ac volutpat risus placerat.</li>
      <li>Suspendisse tellus nisi, feugiat tincidunt sollicitudin sit amet, interdum tempor nunc.</li>
    </ul>
    </section>
    <br>
    <a href="#">SIGN UP NOW</a>
</section>
```

I think the CSS styles on this elements are being overwritten by any other CSS rules in your project (Something like a 3rd party CSS files used in the project). What you can do is, Once your HTML page is rendered in the browser you can right click on the text and choose inspect element, And then a developer window will open, Here you can select each element and see its relevant css rules being applied. If you `use Chrome you can debug this easily`.